# Invoke mouse curser when using task

Tags: wpf

Im using task process and and during the process I want to invoke the mouse
courser ,how should I do that ?

```
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _isEnabled = false;
                        _canBack = false;
....
```

I've tried with the following which is not work...

```
System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Set the window cursor on entry and exit of task***. Since you can access window object only on UI thread so for accessing cursor property you have to delegate it on UI thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                                Cursor = Cursors.Wait));
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Some time consuming operation here.
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                               Cursor = Cursors.Arrow));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() => { Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait; }));
```

Good luck